# Showing that linear map is bounded for $ q = 1.$

Tags: lp-spaces

We have $L: \ell^{2} \to \mathbb{K},$ where $\mathbb{K}$ denotes real or complex space. And $L(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{n^{q}}.$ What I've tried so far is the following.

$ \|L(x)\| = \| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{n^{}} \| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| \frac{x_{n}}{n^{}} \| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \frac{1}{n^{}} \rvert \lvert x_{n}\rvert.$ But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality#Notable_special_cases).

Comment: Why write it as $q$ when you know it is one???

Comment: @copper.hat Edited.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are nearly there and just need to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. In particular,
$$||L(x)||\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{n}\right|\, |x_n|\leq  ||x||_{l^2} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{n}\right|^2\right)^{1/2}=||x||_{l^2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}<\infty.$$
Since $x\in l^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ converges by the $p$ test!

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz is Holder's inequality with $p=q=2$. In this case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |1/n||x_n|\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |1/n|^2\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}=||x||_{l^2}||y||_{l^2}$ where $y=(1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Since $x,y\in l^2$ indeed $L$ is bounded when $q=1$. Are you asking for the result for arbitrary $q$? A similar argument should work.

Comment: But we're assuming that $q=1$; that's what's confusing me. So how can we set $q=2$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Sorry by previous comment was confusing. If we are only considering the case that $q=1$ then don't worry about Holder's inequality but rather look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality. Holder's inequality is a generalisation of this. This is what I have been applying in the solution.

Comment: Yes, Cauchy-Schwarz makes more sense here. Thank you.